# how do I fix this DELETE query?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables: products(product_id,date) and sex(product_id,sex).

I want to DELETE from the products table all products having a product_id for which a row exists in the sex table with this product_id and sex=1.

I also wish to DELETE from the sex table all rows containing a product_id contained in one of the rows I am deleting from the products table. (This may delete multiple rows per product_id.)

So far I have

```
DECLARE @recordsToDelete AS TABLE(
int product_id
);

INSERT INTO @recordsToDelete( product_id )
SELECT product_id 
FROM products p
   JOIN sex s
     ON p.product_id = s.product_id
WHERE s.sex = 1;
```

I will then test with

```
SELECT * FROM @recordsToDelete;
```

before executing

```
DELETE FROM products 
WHERE product_id IN ( SELECT product_id FROM @recordsToDelete );

DELETE FROM sex
WHERE product_id IN ( SELECT product_id FROM @recordsToDelete );
```

but the DECLARE statement is giving me a syntax error. I note [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/declare.html) that DECLARE requires a BEGIN/END compound statement, but I am unable to formulate it properly. How can I correct my mistake?

EDIT:

fixed via

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE recordsToDelete(
product_id INT
);# MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows).
INSERT INTO recordsToDelete( product_id ) 
SELECT p.product_id
FROM products p
JOIN sex s ON p.product_id = s.product_id
WHERE s.sex =1;# Affected rows: 275
SELECT * 
FROM recordsToDelete;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE` to create your table instead of `DECLARE`.

See [this page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html) for more info on creating tables in MySQL.

The syntax you're using is appears to be for MS SQL server, not MySQL. In MySQL, [`DECLARE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/declare.html) is used for local variables, conditions, handlers, and cursors, but **not** for creating tables.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead?

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tempTable
      SELECT product_id  
        FROM products AS p
  INNER JOIN sex AS s
          ON p.product_id = s.product_id 
       WHERE s.sex = 1;

 DELETE FROM products AS p
NATURAL JOIN tempTable AS t
       WHERE p.product_id = t.product_id;
```

Btw, you can't `DELETE FROM same_table (SELECT * FROM same_table)`.

I quote:
`Currently, you cannot delete from a table and select from the same table in a subquery.`

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/delete.html

Comment: thanks I hadn't yet actually performed the DELETE, so I didn't realize that issue. I am wondering what is the purpose of using a NATURAL JOIN versus an INNER JOIN. The documentation suggests a NATURAL JOIN is an INNER JOIN using all columns existing in both tables. If so, is it necessary to have the WHERE clause when using a NATURAL JOIN?

Comment: @jela `NATURAL JOIN` is short hand (notice the lack of the `ON clause`) for when both tables have the same column names i.e. `product_id` is the same name in both tables, so MySQL can figure it out.

Comment: is it then possible to remove the `WHERE` clause from the `DELETE` query, since `NATURAL JOIN` will automatically `JOIN` on the `product_id` columns in the two tables?

Comment: NO!!! The `WHERE` clause in your case is deleting from your `products` table only WHERE there is a match in the temp table on p.product_id & t.product_id. If you remove that where clause you are saying to delete ALL records from the joined table - so your whole products table will disappear.

Comment: but won't the joined table consist of only records for which the `WHERE` condition is already satisfied, given that `NATURAL JOIN` automatically joins on `product_id`? (I've not actually tried this of course, since I realize I'm not understanding something.) I don't understand why the query can't be written `DELETE FROM products AS p INNER JOIN tempTable AS t ON p.product_id=t.product_id` or, if it can, why that's not the same as `DELETE FROM products AS p NATURAL JOIN tempTable AS t` given that tempTable only contains `product_id` values whose rows in the products table should be deleted.

Comment: If I execute `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tempTable SELECT p.product_id
FROM products AS p
INNER JOIN sex AS s ON p.product_id = s.product_id
WHERE s.sex =1;# Affected rows: 275
SELECT * 
FROM products AS p
NATURAL JOIN tempTable AS t
WHERE p.product_id = t.product_id` I get the same as executing `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tempTable SELECT p.product_id
FROM products AS p
INNER JOIN sex AS s ON p.product_id = s.product_id
WHERE s.sex =1;# Affected rows: 275
SELECT * 
FROM products AS p
NATURAL JOIN tempTable AS t`. Since the `SELECT`s are the same, won't the equivalent `DELETE`s be the same?

Comment: @jela looking at it again, yes you are right, the JOIN condition will only select the data that needs to be deleted.

Comment: ok great, I tried the `DELETE` query but I get a syntax error `near 'NATURAL JOIN tempTable' at line 2 `. I tried replacing the `NATURAL JOIN` with an `INNER JOIN` `ON p.product_id = t.product_id` with the same result. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can get what you want from a simple multitable delete:

```
delete sex, products from products p 
inner join sex s on p.id=s.product_id
where s.sex=1
```

You can also consider using `on cascade delete` on your table:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html